# where are the syntax errors am getting?

Tags: c, syntax-error

I am making a program to simulate a game show, randomly. The program picks 1 of three doors for the prize to be hidden behind randomly. The computer picks a door to see if it won or not. This is looped over 10000 times to see how many times I win if I change my pick versus not changing it.

I am getting a bunch of syntax

```
#include  <path-spec>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void count(Status result, Door* pLast_pick, Door* pPick, int* pWin_unchanged, int* pWin_changed);

void randomize_door(Door* pJackpot);

void pick_door(Door* pPick);

Status check(Door* pPick, Door* pJackpot);

enum status {WIN=1,LOSE};

enum door { FIRST=1, SECOND, THIRD };

typedef enum door Door;
typedef enum status Status;

int main(int argc,  char* argv[]){
    int i = 0;
    srand(time);
    Status result;
    Status* pResult = &result ;
    Door jackpot, pick, last_pick=NULL;
    Door* pJackpot = &jackpot, * pPick=&pick, *pLast_pick;
    int win_unchanged = 0, win_changed=0;
    int* pWin_unchanged = &win_unchanged, *pWin_changed=&win_changed;

    while (i < 10000){
        last_pick = NULL;
        randomize_door(pJackpot);
        pick_door(pPick);
        result = check(pPick, pJackpot);
        count(result, pLast_pick, pPick, pWin_unchanged, pWin_changed);

        i++;
    }

    printf("Wins when changed choice: %d  , wins when choice is unchanged: %d", win_changed, win_unchanged);
    return 0;
}

void randomize_door(Door* pJackpot){

    *pJackpot = rand() % 3 + 1;
}

void pick_door(Door* pPick){

    *pPick = rand() % 3 + 1;
}

Status check(Door* pPick, Door* pJackpot){
    if (*pPick == *pJackpot){
        return WIN;
    }
    else{
        return LOSE;
    }
}

void count(Status result, Door* pLast_pick, Door* pPick, int* pWin_unchanged, int* pWin_changed) {
    if (*pLast_pick == *pPick){
        if (result == WIN){
            *pWin_unchanged++;
        }
    }
    else{
        if (result == WIN){
            *pWin_changed++;
        }
    }

    *pLast_pick = *pPick;
}
```

Below are the errors and which lines its happening at. most of them are forgot `}` or `;` which doesn't make any sense in a function header.

```
  1>------ Build started: Project: Program4.1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  daily4.c
daily4.c(4): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'result'
daily4.c(4): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'result'
daily4.c(4): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
daily4.c(4): error C2059: syntax error : ','
daily4.c(4): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
daily4.c(6): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
daily4.c(6): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
daily4.c(6): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
daily4.c(8): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
daily4.c(8): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
daily4.c(8): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
daily4.c(10): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'check'
daily4.c(10): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
daily4.c(10): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
daily4.c(10): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
daily4.c(10): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
daily4.c(10): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
daily4.c(16): error C2370: 'Door' : redefinition; different storage class
daily4.c(10) : see declaration of 'Door'
daily4.c(21): warning C4013: 'srand' undefined; assuming extern returning int
daily4.c(24): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'jackpot'
daily4.c(24): error C2065: 'jackpot' : undeclared identifier
daily4.c(24): error C2065: 'pick' : undeclared identifier
daily4.c(24): error C2065: 'last_pick' : undeclared identifier
daily4.c(24): warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
daily4.c(25): error C2297: '*' : illegal, right operand has type 'int *'
daily4.c(25): error C2065: 'jackpot' : undeclared identifier
daily4.c(25): error C2065: 'pick' : undeclared identifier
daily4.c(25): warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'int *'
daily4.c(25): error C2065: 'pLast_pick' : undeclared identifier
daily4.c(25): error C2100: illegal indirection
daily4.c(30): error C2065: 'last_pick' : undeclared identifier
daily4.c(30): warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
daily4.c(31): warning C4013: 'randomize_door' undefined; assuming extern returning int
daily4.c(32): warning C4013: 'pick_door' undefined; assuming extern returning int
daily4.c(33): warning C4013: 'check' undefined; assuming extern returning int
daily4.c(34): warning C4013: 'count' undefined; assuming extern returning int
daily4.c(34): error C2065: 'pLast_pick' : undeclared identifier
daily4.c(43): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
daily4.c(43): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
daily4.c(43): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
daily4.c(43): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'pJackpot'
daily4.c(48): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
daily4.c(48): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
daily4.c(48): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
daily4.c(48): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'pPick'
daily4.c(53): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
daily4.c(53): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
daily4.c(53): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
daily4.c(53): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
daily4.c(53): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'pJackpot'
daily4.c(62): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
daily4.c(62): error C2081: 'Door' : name in formal parameter list illegal
daily4.c(62): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
daily4.c(62): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
daily4.c(62): error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
daily4.c(62): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: errors are clearly shown in the error stack !

Comment: i know they're telling me the erros. but these errors simply don't exist.

Comment: You need to define the `enum` first and then use them in the function declaration. You have reversed the order.

Comment: What does "please don't vote this down for absolutely no reason." with your software problem. Please (re-)read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) which clearly states: no distractions, no chit-chat.

Comment: Even If you resolve the above errors, You will be left with two more (similar) errors.  `enum door { FIRST=1, SECOND, THIRD }; door last_pick=NULL; ` You cannot use the enum like above.

Comment: Unfortunately, though compilers are very good at assembling machine code from well-formed source code, they are remarkably bad at assembling error-messages.  All of them are bad, (and linkers worse:).  One syntax error can generate pages of utter rubbish as the compiler digs itself an ever-bigger hole. Often, the only thing you can do is look at the first line flagged as erroneous, carefully examine it and 'mess about' until you find out what is really causing the problem, (eg. using enums before declaring them).

Answer (score 2):

sample to fix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //for srand

//enum and typedef defined prior to use 
enum status {WIN=1,LOSE};
enum door { NONE, FIRST=1, SECOND, THIRD };//Define NONE instead of NULL

typedef enum door Door;
typedef enum status Status;


void count(Status result, Door* pLast_pick, Door* pPick, int* pWin_unchanged, int* pWin_changed);
void randomize_door(Door* pJackpot);
void pick_door(Door* pPick);
Status check(Door* pPick, Door* pJackpot);

int main(int argc,  char* argv[]){
    int i = 0;
    Status result;
    Status* pResult = &result ;
    Door jackpot, pick, last_pick=NONE;
    Door* pJackpot = &jackpot, * pPick=&pick, *pLast_pick;
    int win_unchanged = 0, win_changed=0;
    int* pWin_unchanged = &win_unchanged, *pWin_changed=&win_changed;

    srand(time(NULL));//If  you use the equivalent of the C89 compiler can not be mixed the declaration statement and execution statements.

    ...
```

Comment: Please explain what you fixed and why.